# PhoneGap or Calatrava

Tags: web-applications, mobile, cordova

I want to develope some mobile app for iOS, Android and others platforms. I researched appropriate existing solutions and I find two similar tools: **phonegap** and **calatrava**. Can anyone explain key differences between them to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Phonegap and Calatrava are quite different frameworks.

Phonegap is a native wrapper for html/javascript/css applications meaning that you can author applications as if you were developing them for the web and package them as native mobile apps. Phonegap UIs run as html/javascript in UIWebViews, and don't use native UI components. Phonegap has a bunch of javascript interfaces to native functionality not commonly exposed to the web such as as camera and alerts.

Calatrava is a new cross platform framework written by the Thoughtworks folks and its intention is different than phonegap. Whilst phonegap is a "write once run everywhere" framework, Calatrava is designed to give you the benefits of shared application logic whilst giving you the option to use either entirely native views or web views. In Calatrava, application logic is written in javascript (coffeescript actually) and views can be written either in html/javascript or in Objective C for iOS or Java for Android. A common practise is to develop an entire application in Calatrava for the web and then gradually replace the views with native UI for mobiles.